# any resources for the sorrow of god

Tags: resource

We've all had ample resources(albeit they are not enough or typical) for learning the mahimas(greatness), beauty, qualities, nature, form, motives, leelas of god. Yet there remains one more book.

When a mother delivers a child she experiences the immense pain for her creation. I wonder if god experiences a similar yet much magnified pain when from his whole a spark of fire is separated? What is the **sorrow of god**? knowing it all, nothing to gain, nothing to hate nor anything to be surprised of?

Any vedas/scriptures/upanishads/puranas or any scriptic resources that have the answer to this? Please give me the name or resources that mention the answers to this.

Comment: pleasure and pain are part of this world, part of maya. The transcendental Godhead is beyond pleasure and pain.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda , yes that might be true, but as a creator, a nurturer, one who takes care and _gives birth_, what are the things that god faces. Any scriptic sources for that?

Comment: it is said, beyound pleasure and pain, god is in _paramananda_ which is literally extreme joy, it might just be that he just doesn't mention what he faces . That is why his actions are _leelas_ he says what is best.

Comment: I do not have ample resources. What makes you think I do? The first question you pose is specific. The second is very general. Which one do you need to be answered?

Comment: @Wikash_ , I'd like both ofcourse. :-) If possible

Answer (score 1):

In *Gita* 2.14, Krishna says (Swami Gambhirananda translator):

> 14. But the contacts of the organs with the objects are the producers of cold and heat, happiness and sorrow. They have a beginning and an end, (and) are transient. Bear them, O descendant of Bharata.

and in *Gita* 9.8-9, Krishna says:

> 8. Keeping my own Prakrti under control, I project forth again and again the whole of this multitude of beings which are powerless owing to the onfluence of their own nature.
>
> 'In that case, You, who are the Supreme God and who ordain this multitude of beings unequally, will become associated with virtue and vice as a result of that act?'
>   In answer the Lord says this:
>
> 9. O Dhanajaya (Arjuna), nor do these actions bind Me, remaining (as I do) like one unconcerned with, and unattached to, those actions.
>
> [and part of the commentary]...As to that, the Lord states the reason for Him not becoming associated with the actions: *Asinam*, remaining (as I do); *udasinavat*, like one unconcerned, like some indifferent spectator-- for the Self is not subject to change; and *asaktam*, unattached; *tesu karmasu*, to those actions--free from attachment to results, free from the egoism that 'I do'.
>
> Hence, even in the case of any other person also, the absence of the idea of agentship and the absence of attachment to results are the causes of not getting bound. Otherwise, like a silkworm, a foolish man becomes bound by actions. This is the idea.

Brahman is Self-existent, eternal, and unchanging. To have joy or sorrow is to have attachment or a hankering for a transient object - it arises from desire; and as *Gita* 3.34 says "Attraction and repulsion are ordained with regard to the objects of all the organs..."

Comment: I do understand. What is your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Vishnu Purana, 1.12.64 to 68

दिश: श्रोत्रातक्षिति: पद्भयाम त्वत्त: सर्वांभूदिदम |64

न्यग्रोध: सुमहानल्पे यथा बीजे व्यवस्थित:
संयमे विश्वमखिलं बीजभूते तथा त्वयि ||65

बीजाद अंकुर सम्भूतो न्याग्रोदस्तु सामुत्थित:
विस्ताराम च यथा त्वत्तः सृष्टौ तथा जगत ||66

यथा ही कदली नान्या त्वक्पत्रादपी दृष्यते
एवं विश्वस्य नान्यस्त्वं त्वत्स्थायीश्वर दृश्यते ||67

ह्लादिनी संवित त्वयि एका सर्वसंस्थितौ
ह्लादतापकारी मिश्रा त्वयि नो गुणवर्जिता ||68

This whole universe has been manifested by You(Vishnu ).
Just as a seed of a banyan tree grows and remains as a huge tree, in the same way during the time of unmanifestation of this universe, it remains as in its seed form in You(Vishnu).
Just as the seed grows into a sapling and takes up a huge form of a banyan tree in the same way during the time of creation this universe manifests from You and takes up this huge shape.

Oh Supreme controller, just as a banana tree doesn't seem different from its leaves, in the same way You are not different from this manifest universe, this universe is seen to be situated in You.
You who is the basis of all manifestation, in your svarupa You who is- ahladini, samvit and sandhini (sat, chit, ananda)  remain as one.
You  dont experience  material pleasure or pain(from sattva or tamas) or the mixture of both( due to rajas) because You are nirgun(without material qualities).